# Cannot access/modify a folder, even though it shows up in a dir list

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-explorer, rename

I have a folder called S.W.A.T. that cannot be accessed or renamed, possibly because of the full stop characters. It appears in explorer, but produces an error when attempting to open it.

> **Location is not available**
>
> D:\StockPics\S.W.A.T is unavailable. If the location is on this PC, make sure that the device or drive is connected or the disc is inserted, then try again. If the location is on a network, make sure that you're connected to the network or Internet, then try again. If the location still can't be found, it might have been moved or deleted.

[image: IMG:]

Attempting to rename the folder yields the same warning as you would see when changing a file's extension. Windows cannot find the file when proceeding with the rename.

> **Could not find this item**
>
> This is no longer located in D:\StockPics. Verify the item's location and try again.

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

Powershell encounters similar errors. The folder appears in the `dir` list, but can't be found when trying to rename it.

> ```
> PS D:\StockPics> dir
>  
>     Directory: D:\StockPics
>  
> Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
> ----                -------------         ------ ----
> d-----       27/04/2020     15:45                S.W.A.T.
>  
> PS D:\StockPics> Rename-Item 'S.W.A.T.' 'SWAT'
>  
> Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'S.W.A.T.' does not exist.
> At line:1 char:1
> + Rename-Item 'S.W.A.T.' 'SWAT'
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
> ```

[image: IMG:]

Comment: I think that's not because of full stop characters. I tried making a S.W.A.T. folder and I can open it as well but the last full stop automatically gets omitted after creating the folder. Isn't it the same in your case?

Comment: @Sanu_012 Alas, no. The folder was created by an external tool. Windows doesn't let you end a folder name with a dot; I guess for this exact reason.

Comment: 5 seconds google search fetched me this result. Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075753/how-to-delete-a-folder-that-name-ended-with-a-dot
and if it works, please consider researching properly beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for the help. At the time of posting, it wasn't apparent that the trailing dot was the problem. Searching for the title text or Windows errors didn't provide any useful results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the Windows API can't (normally) handle trailing dots or spaces in item names. When a utility that uses the API (like Powershell or Explorer) is responsible for creating the name, illegal trailing characters are automatically removed.

This restriction does not extend to third-party software, however, which can freely create names that Windows would consider invalid. Once created, any Windows utility will fail to perform operations on those items.

There are two workarounds:

1. Use an external tool. 7zip, for example, has a file explorer that is capable of performing operations on items with invalid names.
2. Use Windows' extended-length path mode. By prefixing an absolute path with `\\?\`, the Windows API supports, among other things, items with trailing dots or spaces. The Powershell command in the original question succeeds if rewritten as:

```
PS D:\StockPics> Rename-Item '\\?\D:\StockPics\S.W.A.T.' 'SWAT'
```